Transferring image from between nodes interfere with actions
I wrote two ROS2 (humble) nodes:

Node A with image_transport::Publisher topic and several action servers.
Image topic broadcasts sensor_msgs::Image message of size 800x480@30FPS from dedicated thread.

Node B received image from node A and periodically sends action goals to node B.


I ran both on same PC.
Problem is that if I enable image broadcast from node A it looks like image transfer occupies all resources because action requests/responses stops to go smoothly both from B to A and from A to B. While when no image is being broadcasted all actions respond very immediately.
Is there any tweaks that can be applied so that image channel wouldn't affect actions channel?
Thanks.

I'm interested in this post and would like to try to find out why this is happening. For reference, could you please send your source code? Thank you very much for your help.
